# How to get type of JTextfield from DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

Problem:
I want to know whether can we get the JTextfield type from the DocumentFilter??
I have read java docs and searched a lot but did not find any information.

Need:
I set same DocumentFilter on 2 JTextfields. When the event occur, in the "replace" method of DocumentFilter, I want to know action on which textfield resulted in the event.

Use Case:
I have near about 15 texfields(may increase in future) and I want separate checks on all which are:
- maximum text length for input
- only certain characters must be entered(this will be same for all textfields)
For e.g: textfield1 can take maximum 10 chars but textfield2 can take maximum 5 chars.

What I have done so far:
I have created separate filters for every textfield which results in lots of redundant code and increases complexity to handle, for future use.

Looking forward for any help. :-)

Comment: No, you cannot access it. DocumentFilter is a part of the model (`Document`), and JTextField is the controller.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy sorry didn't get you. :-(

Comment: @Aman I think that he's referring to the fact that there is not a method in `DocumentFilter` class which you can use to obtain the source of a "replace event" (which is not a event), something like `getSource ()` or `getComponent ()`. You can add for example a `CaretListener` on your textfields, but you would better clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ansharja I have already written the need in the question.

Comment: @Aman You said you want to know which textfield resulted in the "event". I'm asking you: *why*? Do you need the document filter to act in a different manner between the two textfields? Then, you could have two classes extending document filter, and maybe a superclass where you keep the logic in common between them. Do you need to perform an action when a character is typed? Once again, you can register a listener on your fields. Other reasons? Since you can't get what you want (check the source from within the filter) we need to know what you really want to achieve to find a different solution

Comment: `I have already written the need in the question` - why do you THINK you need to know which text field has focus? This information is not available in the DocumentFilter. So you need a different solution. If we don't understand the requirement (not your attempt at a solution), then we can't help.

Comment: &*"Need: I set same DocumentFilter on 2 JTextfields. When the event occur, in the "replace" method of DocumentFilter, I want to know action on which textfield resulted in the event."* - Use two different `DocumentFilters` or provide configuration properties to the `DocumentFilter` to change it's actions - the filter should NEVER interact with the text component, this could cause untold issues

Comment: Hello all, I have updated the question. I also have code. If required, I can also update in it.

Comment: @ Aman Ok, check my answer, it should give you the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now your need is more clear but, once again, you can't (and you should not) check which textfield are you typing in from inside the `DocumentFilter` to decide what to do in your `replace ()` method.

Possible solution: create your own `DocumentFilter` class, passing all the parameters you need (maximum text length, and maybe an array of forbidden characters, or whatever else).
All your textfields will have a distinct `DocumentFilter` instance, with the parameters set in order to suit your needs. This way you will have a clean solution without reduntant code.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
public class FilterTextField
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new MainPanel ());
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MainPanel () {
        super (new GridLayout (3, 1, 0, 20));

        JTextField t1 = new JTextField (20);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField (20);
        JTextField t3 = new JTextField (20);

        ((AbstractDocument) t1.getDocument ()).setDocumentFilter (new MyDocumentFilter (5));
        ((AbstractDocument) t2.getDocument ()).setDocumentFilter (new MyDocumentFilter (10, '!', '?'));
        ((AbstractDocument) t3.getDocument ()).setDocumentFilter (new MyDocumentFilter (15, new char [] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}));

        add (t1);
        add (t2);
        add (t3);

        setBorder (new EmptyBorder (20, 20, 20, 20));
    }


}
class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    private char [] forbiddenCharacters;
    private int maximumLength;

    public MyDocumentFilter (int maximumLength, char ... forbiddenCharacters) {
        this.maximumLength = maximumLength;
        this.forbiddenCharacters = forbiddenCharacters;
    }
    @Override public void replace (FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        // Get the full text you would have after replacement
        Document document = fb.getDocument ();
        String fullText = new StringBuilder (document.getText (0, document.getLength ())).replace (offset, offset + length, text).toString ();
        // Check your requirements ...
        if (fullText.length () <= maximumLength) {
            if (forbiddenCharacters != null) {
                for (char c : forbiddenCharacters) if (fullText.indexOf (c) > -1) return;
            }
            // Replace method is called only if your requirements are met.
            super.replace (fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a working solution. Maybe some more clarification with code comments will be helpful for others also. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Aman I'm glad it helped. Where do you think i should put more comments to clarify?

Comment: There could be some explanation for MyDocumentFilter parameters. Other is that String fullText line since so many things are happening in that 1 line. :-P

Comment: @Aman I think it comes clear by checking documentation for `DocumentFilter` [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html#replace(javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet)) method and [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) usage